# Zend update() gives out application error even with correct parameters

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I am using `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_HTTP()` to upload a file (image) and then with `Application_Model_DbTable_User()` to update the `users` mysql table with the corresponding path of the file .

This is the action in the controller :

```
public function profileAction() {

    $form = new Application_Form_Updateprofile();
    $users = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
    $session = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
    $adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_HTTP();

    $loggedUser = $session->read()->username;
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $adapter->setDestination('ProfilePhotos');
        $filename = pathinfo($form->image->getFileName());
        $adapter->addFilter('Rename', uniqid() . '.' . $filename['extension']);

        if (!$adapter->receive()) {
            $messages = $adapter->getMessages();
            echo implode("\n", $messages);
        } else {
            $userProfilePhoto = $adapter->getFileName('image');
            $users->UpdateProfilePic($loggedUser, $userProfilePhoto);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function `UpdateProfilePic()` in the `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_HTTP()` :

```
 public function UpdateProfilePic($username, $img_address) {

    $bind = array("profile_pic" => $img_address);
    $where = "username = $username";
    $this->_db->update($this->_name, $bind, $where);
}
```

Var_dump($username,$img_address,$bind,$where)
Output :

```
    $img_address - string(31) "ProfilePhotos\5429294234ebe.gif"
    $username - string(7) "Tiberiu"
    $bind - array(1) { ["profile_pic"]=> string(31) "ProfilePhotos\5429294234ebe.gif" }
    $where - string(18) "username = Tiberiu"
```

`Users` table :

```
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `profile_pic` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is my first attempt on Zend_File_Upload and although the file transfer is a success it won't update the `users` table and I can't figure out why , I've checked the manual and I think I'm feeding the correct parameters to the `update()` action.

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message please?

Comment: Are you getting only error message like application error?

Comment: It would just say 'Application Error' . I've found out , what was the problem in my `$where = "username = $username";` I didn't add semicolons , it should be `$where = "username = '$username' ";`

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in `UpdateProfilePic()` function in my db class .
It should be :

```
 $where = "`username` = '$username'";
```

Instead of :

```
 $where = "`username` = $username";
```